# room query to return object from 1 table with filters from another table

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I got main object in `table-A`. `table-B` consists of some `ids` of objects in `table-A` of and `time in millis`. I want to get those objects from `table-A` whose `id` is in `table-B` sorted by `time in millis` in table-B.
I got the unsorted objects with this query:

```
Select * from $table-A where id in (Select id from $table-B)
```

I am stuck on sorting them by the time in `table-B`

Comment: Sorted by which time? The earliest, the last one, the average time?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @TheImpaler sorted asc or desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `join`:

```
Select *
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
order by b.time_in_milliseconds
```